# What kind of installer does Spotify use?

Tags: installation, spotify

I noticed Spotify loads a ~90kb installer and then downloads the required components afterwards. I wasn't able to figure out if this is custom build or if they use a free/purchase installer system. What kind of installer does Spotify use then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically the little Spotify installer isn't an installer — it's a tiny application that uses system APIs to download and extract the full Spotify download, which includes a proper installer. Once the download is complete, the tiny installer launches the proper installer which takes over the installation process.

Disclaimer: I work for Spotify and wrote the first version of the Mac installer.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what was the motivation behind such design. (Disclaimer: I haven't used Spotify and know nothing about it...)

Comment: Spotify is all about being fast, and that extends to our installers too. A tiny installer gets the user up and running with Spotify software on their computer nice and quickly, even if it's just a "Please wait" window.

Comment: So it's all custom code, no purchased components/installer framework involved?

Comment: I believe that's the case.

Comment: @Uwe I believe Advanced Installer has an option to create a small exe program that downloads an MSI from a URL. I haven't used it, but it's called a "Web Installer" under their Media section of an AI project. Not sure if it works for non-MSI based installs though.